# Why does Mono.doOnSuccess() suppress errors?

Tags: project-reactor

In the following code snippet, an exception is thrown, as is to be expected:

```java
@Test
public void testError()
{
    Mono.error(new NullPointerException())
        .subscribe();
}
```

However, in the following code snippet no exception is thrown:

```java
@Test
public void testErrorWithDoOnSuccess()
{
    Mono.error(new NullPointerException())
        .doOnSuccess(aValue -> {})
        .subscribe();
}
```

When I use the block operator instead of the subscribe operator, the exception works again:

```java
@Test
public void testErrorWithDoOnSuccessAndBlock()
{
    Mono.error(new NullPointerException())
        .doOnSuccess(aBoolean -> {})
        .block();
}
```

The documentation of the `Mono.doOnSuccess` operator does not say anything specifically about its behavior w.r.t. errors, but I wouldn't expect this behavior at all given the name of the operator. Why does it suppress exceptions (and only when not using the block operator)? Is this intended behavior, or is this a bug?

Reactor version used is the most recent one at time of writing, `3.1.8.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, the operator should suppress the "No error callback implemented" exception **only** in the case where you use `doOnTerminate`/`doAfterTerminate`, not `doOnSuccess`...

That said, operator still propagates the NPE and this bug is easily worked around by implementing best practices: *always define at least value handler and error handler in `subscribe(...)`*.

Comment: Could you please take also a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148272/mock-services-in-spring-reactor/54148631#54148631 ? I tried to use `doOnSuccess()` in my case, but it seems that it won't return a `Mono<Throwable>` in case of error. And regarding `then()` I'm not so sure why the service is called for an incorrect amount of times. I'm using Reactor: `3.2.5.RELEASE`.