# Mock services in Spring Reactor

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-webflux, reactor

Let's take a look over this simple method:

```
public Mono<SuccessResponse> doSomething(){
        return service1.doSomething()
            .then(service2.doSomething2())
            .thenReturn(new SuccessResponse("Awesome")));
}
```

So basically I want to test this method for a scenario in which, service1.doSomething() will throw an error:

```
when(service1.doSomething()).thenReturn(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("Something bad happened")));
when(service2.doSomething()).thenReturn(Mono.just(new SomeResponse()))

assertThatThrownBy(() -> testedService.doSomething().block())
            .isExactlyInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class);

verify(service2, never()).doSomething(); //Why this is executed!?
```

My question is why service2.doSomething() is executed once? it shouldn't be executed since service1.doSomething() throw an error above...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why the `service2.doSomething()` method is invoked is that while a `Mono` can be lazy, plainly calling an operator isn't. You are eagerly calling the methods that will return lazy `Mono`s, thus assembling a processing pipeline.

If you inline your code, it becomes a bit clearer I think:

```
    //exception is CREATED immediately, but USED lazily
return Mono.error(new IllegalStateException())
    //mono is CREATED immediately. The data it will emit is also CREATED immediately. But it all triggers LAZILY.
    .then(Mono.just(new SomeResponse()))
    //note that then* operators completely ignore previous step's result (unless it is an error)
    .thenReturn(new SuccessResponse("Awesome")));
```

Some operators accept `Supplier` or `Function` which provides a lazy alternative to this eager construction style. One universal way of doing that is to use `Mono.defer`:

```
public Mono<SuccessResponse> doSomething(){
        return service1.doSomething()
            .then(Mono.defer(service2::doSomething2))
            .thenReturn(new SuccessResponse("Awesome")));
}
```

**But I'd argue that**, *unless `service2` hides a source that is NOT lazy (eg. a `Mono` adapted from a `CompletableFuture`)*, **the problem is not the `doSomething` but the test**.

With the `service2` mock, you are essentially testing the assembly of the chain of operators, but not if that step in the pipeline is actually executed.

One trick available in `reactor-test` is to wrap the `Mono.just`/`Mono.error` in a `PublisherProbe`. This can be used to mock a `Mono` like you did, but with the added feature of providing assertions on the execution of the `Mono`: was it subscribed to? was it requested?

```
//this is ultimately tested by the assertThrownBy, let's keep it that way:
when(service1.doSomething()).thenReturn(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("Something bad happened")));

//this will be used to ensure the `service2` Mono is never actually used: 
PublisherProbe<SomeResponse> service2Probe = PublisherProbe.of(Mono.just(new SomeResponse()));
//we still need the mock to return a Mono version of our probe
when(service2.doSomething()).thenReturn(service2Probe.mono());

assertThatThrownBy(() -> testedService.doSomething().block())
            .isExactlyInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class);

//service2 might have returned a lazy Mono, but it was never actually used:
probe.assertWasNotSubscribed();
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, that was interesting and super useful!

Comment: very useful! Thanks. I wasted so much time debugging this

Answer (score 0):

`thenReturn` is not for throwing error ! You need to use `thenThrow()` and also you don't need to write mock method for service2 , just do verify which have called

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work like in non-reactive cases with `thenThrow()`, that's why I used the `thenReturn()`. The test contain multiple testing scenarios, that's why the service2 is mocked, but agreed I could use do verify otherwise.

Comment: Reactor works by wrapping errors as specific asynchronous signals. It translates it back to a `throw` only  when you try to go back to blocking imperative code (using `.block()`).